# Confusion about setting Variables

Tags: node.js, variables, discord, discord.js

OK, this may sound like a really simple question, but the below code keeps giving me an error on the console.  After some research, it looks as though I may have messed up setting the variables, but I'm not sure how to fix.
For context, this module is to update channels with server stats.
Code:

```js
function updateStats(client) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const config = require("../settings/configuration");
    const settings = require("../settings/configuration");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID);
    const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('883654989271154728');
    const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('883655041813200926');
    setInterval(function() {
    const interval = (async function() {
        for await (const startTime of setInterval(interval, Date.now())) {
          const now = Date.now();
          console.log(now);
          if ((now - startTime) > 1000)function updateStats(client) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const config = require("../settings/configuration");
    const settings = require("../settings/configuration");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID);
    const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('883654989271154728');
    const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('883655041813200926');
    setInterval(function() {
    const interval = (async function() {
        for await (const startTime of setInterval(interval, Date.now())) {
          const now = Date.now();
          console.log(now);
          if ((now - startTime) > 1000)
            break;
        }
        console.log(Date.now());
      })(); 
      console.log('Getting stats update..')
      var userCount = guild.memberCount;
      var onlineCount = guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
      $console.log("Total Users: " + userCount);
      $console.log("Online Users: " + onlineCount);
      totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      }, 30000)
        }
    module.exports = {
    updateStats
    }
            break;
        }
        console.log(Date.now());
      })(); 
      console.log('Getting stats update..')
      var userCount = guild.memberCount;
      var onlineCount = guild.members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
      console.log("Total Users: " + userCount);
      console.log("Online Users: " + onlineCount);
      totalUsers.setName("Total Users: " + userCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      onlineUsers.setName("Online Users: " + onlineCount)
      .then(newChannel => console.log(`Stat channel renamed to: ${newChannel.name}`))
      .catch(console.error);
      }, 30000)
        }
    module.exports = {
    updateStats
    }
```

Error on console:

```
[Error] An error happened in process: 
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'interval' before initialization
    at /home/container/events/Stats.js:10:51
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/container/events/Stats.js:49:9)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward error message. You use the word `interval` while defining `interval`

Comment: Pretty hard to read the code in your question without proper indentation.  Many will just skip over questions like this.  Please make it easier to read your code.

Comment: I don’t think you understand `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `const interval = (async function() {` to `let interval = (async function() {` and then just use `interval = (async function() {`
like that:

```js
    let interval = (async function() {
        for await (const startTime of setInterval(interval, Date.now())) {
          const now = Date.now();
          console.log(now);
          if ((now - startTime) > 1000)function updateStats(client) {
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const config = require("../settings/configuration");
    const settings = require("../settings/configuration");
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(settings.BOT_SETTINGS.Guild_ID);
    const totalUsers = client.channels.fetch('883654989271154728');
    const onlineUsers = client.channels.fetch('883655041813200926');
    setInterval(function() {
    interval = (async function() {
```